# C# string 4096 limit?

Tags: c#, string

Lately I have encountered a very strange C# string problem. I tried search everywhere but could not find a solution. Bear with me if this question is too simple since I am very new to C#.

I used a c# string variable to hold the html text from webbrowser.

```
string webresult = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

Somehow it only holds the first 4096 bytes from the html text.
I use  :

```
Console.Out.WriteLine (webresult.Length);
```

and the console's output is 4096.

But if I dump it into a file, all the rest of html file will output fine.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"web.html", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
try
{
    // read from file or write to file
    StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);                
    m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0}", str);
    m_streamWriter.Flush();
}
finally
{
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Can anyone please help with this issue? Thanks

Comment: This is not a limit of C# or .NET String length. What changes? Either *where* it is dumped to or *how* it is read.

Comment: What's the size in bytes of web.html?

Comment: (If this is specifically about WebBrowserControl.DocumentText, please tag it as such.)

Comment: Why is the variable called "webresult" in the text but "str" in the snippet?  Clearly this needs a better snippet.

Comment: the web.html is about 900k. The variale is called str in the snippet because that is inside another function. Thanks

Comment: If you set a breakpoint before the `Console.Out.WriteLine` call and inspect the length.. what does it say?

Comment: Also: Note that neither `Console.Out.WriteLine` nor the CLR limit the size of a string (up until the theoretical maximum.. thereby running out of memory..).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that 4096 char limit is tied to a http call, so that's what I would look into for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like when you are getting DocumentText the page hasn't been fully loaded.  I think the WebBrowser throws an event when its load is complete (`DocumentCompleted`).  You should do your text dump in a handler for that event.

Comment: yeah, it is inside documentcompleted.  private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

            string webresult = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            Console.Out.WriteLine (webresult.Length);